# How to yank character under cursor?

Tags: copy-paste, yank

I want to copy just one character underneath the cursor. Its not ascii, so I can't type it. Is there a function or key that allows for this?

Vanilla emacs welcome, though evil and spacemacs answers are also acceptable.

Comment: I suppose you want to copy a char to insert it somewhere. If you know the char number, why not simply insert it where you want it to be ? M-:(insert-char (read-number "char: ") ) ? Or you can compose an interactive function to do it. If you don't know how to do it, ask for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three keys, as observed by view-lossage

```
 C-SPC                   ;; set-mark-command
 C-f                     ;; forward-char
 <escape> w              ;; kill-ring-save
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this function in your init file:

```
    (defun kill-ring-save-char-at-point ()
    "save the character at point in the kill-ring "
      (interactive)
      (unless (eq (point) (point-max))
        (kill-ring-save (point) (1+ (point)))))
```

and bind it to a key of your choice.

Comment: I like this answer, but I preferr to use motions already defined by emacs. Still, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to copy the characters to a register. C-SPC C-f C-x r s to record them then C-x r i to play them back.

Answer (score 0):

spacemacs (evil):
Copy: vy
Paste: p

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Can you please explain your answer in more detail.

Comment: v - visual mod. Char under cursor is already selected. Now "y" to copy end exit visual mod.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the material you put in your comment.

Comment: This is my favorite, though it would be nicer if the comment was added to the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to GNU Emacs too (Doom Emacs user before). I found out a command that can fit the need:

1. `M-@` (`Alt+@`): select word under cusor.
2. `M-w`: copy the word selected.
3. Done.

But it needs to move the cursor in the beginning of word firstly.